# Prove/Disprove: $f(x)=x^5$ is continuous in $(\mathbb{Z},d_{3})$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Prove/Disprove: $f(x)=x^5$ is continuous in $(\mathbb{Z},d_{3})$ where $d_{3}$ is p-adic metric

The proof process is like the case in real analysis?

We start with $d_{3}(f(x)-f(a))<\epsilon$ and trying to find $\delta$ as expression of $\epsilon$ such that for $d_{3}(x,a)<\delta$ we get $d_{3}(f(x)-f(a))<\epsilon$

$$d_{3}(f(x)-f(a))=x^5-a^5=(x-a)(x^4+ax^3+a^2x^2+a^3x+a^4)$$

How should I continue?

Comment: It shouldn't be very hard to prove $d_3(x^5-y^5)\le d_3(x-y)$, so the function is Lipschitz.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks, but as for now I need to prove it by definition

Comment: With the Lipschitz property your "proof from definition" will be straightforward.